# Validate react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

if(value.length < 5){

console.log('success')

}

else{

console.log('fail')

`enter code here`
}

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 if (name.length < 5){
    alert('length data < 5')
}
```